# Support of function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, second-countable, support-function

As reported in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics), for a function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we can define some notion of $supp(f)$, in particular:

1. If $X$ is only a set, we define the **theoretical support**,
2. If $(X, \tau)$ is also equipped with a topological structure, we define the **closed support** and **compact support**,
3. If $(X, \tau, \mu, \mathscr{B})$ has a topological structure and also is equipped by a measure, we define the **essential support**,

I have two different question:

(1) Why, if it is present an a topological structure, are we interested to define the support of a function as a *closed* subset of $X$?

(2)The essential support is, in some sense, the natural extencion of the closed support that can work with the function defined $\mu$-almost everywhere.
However, we can easily show that:

**Thm:** If $(X, \tau, \mu, \mathscr{B})$ is second-countably space, Then a measurable non zero function $f:(X, \tau, \mu, \mathscr{B}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mu$-a.e. zero on $(ess\, supp(f))^C$

Then for a non second-countably space, we are not guarantee of this result.
Then is it still a well-formulated notion?

Comment: I would think we're interested in _closed_ supports so that we can use the theory continuous functions.

Comment: I dont understand the point. If we have a continuous function, $f^{-1}(\{0\}^C) Is naturally an open set, why Is better to take his closure?

Comment: I found the term "carrier" of a function $f$ for the set $\{x\in X: f(x)\neq0\}$ more adequate than theoretical support. Support is more appropriate for functions defined on topological spaces, in which case, the support of $f$ is the closure of its carrier. The support is of interest (more do that the carrier) in many situations because it excludes "thin" sets of points where a function has vigaviour which is in a way different that what happens in thick sets. This is all hand wavy but it make sense when one studies specific problems.

Comment: ''compact support'' is not another definition of support, it is meant as in ``functions with compact support'' where support means what wikipedia calls closed support.